# Setting a lighter (white) scrollbar color in Lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

My (cocoa) application has an usability problem with Lion (OS X 10.7). There is a scrollable component that has a dark background, so it is hard to see the default transparent dark scrollbar.

Is there a way to replace the appearance of the scrollbars with a lighter (white) one? Safari and other browsers seem to do this dynamically based on the websites backgrounds, but I have found no easy solution for a native cocoa application. Is there a solution that do not involve subclassing NSScrollView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[myScrollView setScrollerKnobStyle:NSScrollerKnobStyleLight];
```

From the [NSScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/setScrollerKnobStyle%3a).

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I didn't see that in the official documentation...

Comment: Oh, I know now: because the project is built with the 10.5 API. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If your window is created in IB, you can change the scroller style in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: Great! That is even better because that way I don't have to write specific code for Lion. I must have been blind, but again I didn't find anything for a week on the net.